# Webstorm: bootstrap autocomplete templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webstorm

Can I know how can I get the bootstrap autocomplete templates (enabling you to type "navbar,"container", "row", etc)?

For example at 10:40 of this video , The author types navbar on the html page he gets the bootstrap intellisense. How can I set up this on Webstorm.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q2OCDeI-ew

Answer (score 2):

The author must be using Live Templates (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/live-templates.html). WebStorm doesn't come with bundled live templates for bootstrap. But you can try creating your own ones or use the plugins available in the repository: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7390?pr=phpStorm and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7572?pr=phpStorm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the word autocomplete, you need to **import the Framework** into your **IDE**. I had the same problem, after several attempts I managed to import **Bootstrap**.

I am using **Web Storm**, version **WS-173.4127.31 of 26 December 2017**.

To import your Framework you must follow the following path:

`File > Settings.. > Languages & Frameworks`

*From here you decide how to organize yourself.
For example, I did the following steps to import Bootstrap:*

`Languages & Frameworks > Template Data Languages`

*Here I set:*

1. Project Language: **CSS**
2. Click on the **+**
3. I selected **bootstrap.min.css**
4. Click on **OK**

*After a few seconds I managed to have the autocompletion of the words!*

[Menù page | WebStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFXV.png)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is trying to figure this out in 2021, just make sure you've downloaded a local copy of the library by using `alt-enter` on the `<link src='bootstrap.min.css'>` tag.

See https://www.facebook.com/JetBrains/posts/webstorm-20193-tip-if-youre-using-bootstrap-or-another-css-library-linked-from-a/2677915872231650/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The example video isn't accessable anymore, but maybe you are looking for [emmet](https://emmet.io/)